# What are the characters in the image?

Tags: character-identification

I need to find the actual text characters in this image.

[image]

I tried an online OCR and this is what I got.

万正嬴体简体

万正赢体简体

万正搔体简体

万正粗们简体

MS P二儡彭、y′又

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are font names

方正康体简体 (Standard kang Simplified)

[image: 方正康体简体]

方正粗倩简体 (Standard Bold Qian Simplified)

[image: 方正粗倩简体]

ＭＳ Ｐゴシック (MS P Gothic)

[image: ＭＳ Ｐゴシック]